# Has anyone been able to get Ubuntu 12.10 to run on a LT4004U netbook?

Tags: xorg, graphics, 12.10, ubuntu-netbook

I recently purchased a new netbook (Gateway LT4004u) and am realizing I should have taken the thing back the instant it started having issues. When I upgraded the hardware (RAM and battery) in the netbook, I installed Ubuntu 12.10, and to my dismay, I found that the system would not even boot! It would display the loading screen, and then the display would suddenly blank out, and it would not respond to any input. Help? Anyone? I think this may be due to an issue with the Intel GMA 3600 GPU in the netbook. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

As of now the only solution I know is to avoid Ubuntu 12.10 and install Ubuntu 12.04 or anything else (recent). I wouldn't expect big news for at least a couple of weeks.
I searched a lot and with some work it seems that you can make it work with the vesa driver, which IMHO is unacceptable.